# animated flatlist with animated ref typescript error

Tags: react-native, expo

Why I get this ts error ?

```
(property) ref: React.RefObject<FlatList<any>>
Type '{ ref: RefObject<FlatList<any>>; data: IInstructionsData[]; renderItem: ListRenderItem<IInstructionsData>; ... 6 more ...; showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { ItemSeparatorComponent?: ComponentType<any> | AnimatedNode<ComponentType<any> | null | undefined> | null | undefined; ... 146 more ...; simultaneousHandlers?: Ref<...> | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { ItemSeparatorComponent?: ComponentType<any> | AnimatedNode<ComponentType<any> | null | undefined> | null | undefined; ... 146 more ...; simultaneousHandlers?: Ref<...> | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }'.ts(2322)
```

Code:

```
import Animated, { useAnimatedScrollHandler, useSharedValue, useDerivedValue, useAnimatedRef } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const AnimatedFlatlist = (Animated.createAnimatedComponent(
  FlatList
) as unknown) as <T>(props: RNGHFlatListProps<T>) => React.ReactElement;

        <AnimatedFlatlist
          ref={flatlistRef}
          data={mockData}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          onScroll={handleScroll}
          keyExtractor={(item, i) => i.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={2}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
```

the error comes at AnimatedFlatlist on ref

what I am doing wrong and how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is incomplete. Where did you define the ref for the AnimatedFlatList?

It should look something like this:

```
const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList<T>>(null);
```

Comment: what is T here ?

Comment: A generic type describing the flatlist item's type. Check this out: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html